# Can't create indexed view with schemabinding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexed-view

I'm trying to script a pretty straight-forward indexed view but SQL is simply refusing my efforts. I've tried researching the issue but haven't had any luck, and unfortunately I'm not exactly a SQL expert so I'm not sure if there's something simple that I'm missing. The template for this script was handed to me by a DBA, but he doesn't know any more than I do. Here's the top end of the script where the first error appears:

```
--Set the options to support indexed views.  
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;  
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,  
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;  
GO  
--Create view with schemabinding.  
IF OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[APIMenus]', 'view') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[APIMenus] ;  
GO  
BEGIN
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[APIMenus]  
    WITH SCHEMABINDING  
    AS  
        SELECT  
            [t0].[GroupName] AS [defaultValue], 
            [t1].[GroupName] AS [transValue],.....
```

The error is `"CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch"` but from what I understand, wrapping it in the `BEGIN...END` with proper `GO` statements before and after should have solved the problem, yet it persists. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is accurate. Wrapping a `CREATE VIEW` in `BEGIN/END` does not work to avoid this message.  If you remove the `BEGIN/END` entirely, so the batch starts with `CREATE VIEW` and ends with another `GO` after the view is defined, then the error will be gone, and you can continue to use this `DROP` before `CREATE` structure.

A slightly different way to handle this problem of not creating a view that already exists, is to invoke dynamic SQL:

```
if OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[cars]', 'view') IS NOT NULL 
    exec ('create view cars as select * from vans where type=1')
go
```

Sometimes I have seen this:

```
if OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[cars]', 'view') IS NOT NULL 
    exec ('create view cars as select 1')
go
alter view cars as
    select * from vans where type==1
GO
```

This latter technique has the advantage that your complex SQL is not embedded in a string, and you can format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Check DROP VIEW IF EXISTS and CREATE OR ALTER VIEW, both supported in SQL Server 2016. 
Ref:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/11/17/create-or-alter-another-great-language-enhancement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/